# Oracle Glassfish 3.1.2 and JMS deployment descriptor files exception

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I created a J2EE web application (war + EJB module) and I tryed to setup JMS resources for Oracle Glassfish 3.1.2.2; the project links on github (web application and EJB module) are:
[J2EE web application](https://github.com/sitMCella/SampleGlassfishApp01) 
[EJB module](https://github.com/sitMCella/SampleGlassfishApp01EjbModule) 
 
I want to setup the JMS resources (JMS factory and JMS destination) on Oracle Glassfish with Java/Glassfish deployment descriptor files. 
The following exception is thrown by Oracle Glassfish during deployment:

```
[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.298+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.361+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.362+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=SampleGlassfishApp01-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.436+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8007: Unsupported deployment descriptors element message-destination value null|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.470+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception registering ejb bundle level resources
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:302)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [null] is not an allowed property value type
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.ResourceReferenceDescriptor.checkType(ResourceReferenceDescriptor.java:505)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.addResourceReferences(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:444)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.addJNDIBindings(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:542)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.bindToComponentNamespace(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:193)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:298)
... 55 more
|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.471+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.473+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : Exception registering ejb bundle level resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [null] is not an allowed property value type
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.ResourceReferenceDescriptor.checkType(ResourceReferenceDescriptor.java:505)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.addResourceReferences(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:444)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.addJNDIBindings(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:542)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.bindToComponentNamespace(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:193)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:298)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2014-07-29T09:23:24.477+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : Exception registering ejb bundle level resources. Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

The deployment descriptors WEB-INF/web.xml, WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml and META-INF/glassfish-ejb-jar.xml do not correctly setup JMS resources and "Unsupported deployment descriptors element message-destination value null" exception is thrown.
How can I solve this problem ?

Best wishes

**Edit**

Resolved with WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml deploymenrt descriptor, see github updated applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml deploymenrt descriptor, see github updated applications.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created JMS resources on Glassfish, right?

Add ejb-jar.xml into EJB module (src/main/resources/META-INF) with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>SampleGlassfishApp01EjbModule</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
            <ejb-name>OldJmsMessageConsumer</ejb-name>
            <local-bean />
            <ejb-class>it.glassfish.examples.sampleproject.ejb</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <resource-ref>
                <description />
                <res-ref-name>jms/EM2Factory</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
            </resource-ref>
            <resource-ref>
                <description />
                <res-ref-name>jms/SimpleQueue</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
            </resource-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: No, JMS resources are application specific, they are created during application deployment through deployment descriptor files. In EJB module I inserted a META-INF/glassfish-ejb-jar.xml that do the same things of META-INF/ejb-jar.xml descriptor file. If I insert the META-INF/ejb-jar.xml as you suggested, Oracle Glassfish throw the following exception during deployment: [...] Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Message-Destination-Ref jms/SimpleQueue@java.lang.String@null [...] javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jms/SimpleQueue'

Comment: Is it possible that Web project is initialized after EJB project, and therefore EJB project is failing? Could you try removing glassfih-resources into EJB project?

Comment: There is no glassfish-resources.xml file in EJB module project

Comment: I understand it: can you move glassfish-resources.xml from Web module into EJB module (directory that contains glassfish-ejb.xml).

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, the question was confusing ("try removing..."); I've tried to move glassfish-resources.xml deployment descriptor file to EJB module (META-INF/glassfish-resources.xml), but the exception is the same as the first one I reported